# Why do I get "data mismatch in criteria expression" when hour() = 0?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to write a query so that if a datestamp occurs at midnight (0:00:00) then it will be shown as 7 hours ahead (7:00:00).

I have the following:

```
select iif(hour(m.date_resolve)=0 and minute(m.date_resolve)=0 
and second(m.date_resolve)=0,dateadd(m.date_resolve,"h",7),m.date_resolve)
as dateForUpload from dataSet
```

This gives me a "data mismatch in criteria expression" error, but if I change the `hour()` part of the `iif` condition as follows:

```
hour(m.date_resolve)=1
```

then this error disappears.

I have tried:

```
hour(m.date_resolve)<1
```

but that also gives me the "data mismatch" error.

Why is it a problem to check if `hour()=0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the error would show up that way.  The main error I see is in `dateadd()`.  The interval should be first:

```
select iif(hour(m.date_resolve)=0 and minute(m.date_resolve)=0 and second(m.date_resolve)=0,
           dateadd("h", 7, m.date_resolve), m.date_resolve) as dateForUpload
from dataSet;
```